# Way to store variable value is different than the way to store variable address(location)

Tags: php

Is it true that the syntax for (assign of variable value) is different than the syntax for (assign of address) in PHP.

Like:
If we want to store **variable value** to another variable then we can do it like this:

```
$b=2;
$a=$b;
print $a;
print $b;
// output is 22
```

But if we want to store **variable address** to another variable then we can do it like this:

```
$b=2;
$a=&$b; // note the & operator
$a=3;
print $a;
print $b;
// output is 33
```

Note that first time $b contain '2' then after $a=&$b; $b will contain '3' , now the point to think that if we want to store variable value then we will use `$a=$b;` & if we want to store variable location address then we will use `$a=&$b;`

*My conclusion:*

The way of **value** storing is like:

```
$store_destination = $store_source;   // ie: value save from right to left.
```

but the way of **address** storing is like:

```
$store_source = $store_destination;   // ie: address save from left to right.
```

> Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP we don't talk about address and pointers explicitly, instead we talk about a concept called [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

In case 2, you are making `$b` a reference to `$a` as a result of which they both refer to the same content. Any change made to either will also change the other.

Comment: well i already know what the code is doing but i just want to confirm the two different ways of storing values (actual value & reference).